# Why does Zsh correct ssh User@ip1 to User@ip2, and how to stop it?

Tags: zsh, macos, autocorrection

On Mac OS X 10.9 and `zsh` version 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) the `ssh user@192.168.13.2` command traps a correct to `ssh User@192.168.12.2 [nyae]`.

I don't want to disable zsh correction on the ssh command completely.

How figure out why zsh wants to make this correct, and prevent it from occurring?

Regression:

- `ssh User@192.168.13.3` also zsh correct to `User@192.168.12.2`
- `ssh 192.168.13.2` does not trap the zsh correct to `ssh 192.168.12.2`
- `ssh User@192.168.13.4` does not zsh correct to `User@192.168.12.2`
- there is a `.zsh_history` file of 2013 while zsh is configured for a maximum history of 2000 commands
- removing all occurences of `ssh User@192.168.12.2` from .zsh_history doesn't improve
- both 192.168.13.2 and 192.168.12.2 list as host on tab completion

```
$ cat .zshrc
setopt correctall
```

Comment: Please share your `.zshrc` (and any file that it includes), or even better, a reduced version of your `.zshrc` that reproduces the problem. Autocorrect is disabled by default, and it's difficult to know what's causing this behavior when we don't know which features you've enabled.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' A minimal `.zshrc` has been appended.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (with a slightly different version). I don't think the history file would matter if you don't enable history, but I might be wrong, or the system configuration might be enabling history. Can you reproduce this with `env HOME=/none zsh -f` and typing `setopt correctall` at the command line?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, with `env HOME=/none zsh -f` and `setopt correctall` I can reproduce the undesired autocorrect.